# Facebook send message automatically when opening a conversation

Tags: facebook, chatbot, messenger

I have a fan page on Facebook and now I want to send a SPECIFIC MESSAGE to some users right after opening the conversation with them (open the conversations manually). Although looking over facebook apis but I still have no idea to do that. Any can hint me some keywords or something can help me to get that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set a greeting text with the API, even including the name of the user:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/welcome-screen/